# Semaphore using two threads not working as expected

Tags: java, semaphore

I am trying to understand the semaphore with the below code, but the thread is not working as expected. I have created two threads using lambda to output two different strings. There are two methods to print the output from the thread. When method1 prints the output, it will wait for method2 to print the output. This process happens alternatively. I think it has some dead lock situation. Can somebody help to fix the code?

Sample output:

```
FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar
```

```java
public class printThread {
    private int n=5;
    private Semaphore f= new Semaphore(1);
    private Semaphore t=new Semaphore(0);
    public void foo(Runnable printFoo) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            f.acquire();
            printFoo.run();
            t.release();
        }
    }

    public void bar(Runnable printBar) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            t.acquire();
            printBar.run();
            f.release();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printThread pt = new printThread();
        Runnable printFo=()-> System.out.print("Foo");
        Runnable printBa=()-> System.out.print("Bar");
        try {
            pt.foo(printFo);
            pt.bar(printBa);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Despite naming your class `printThread` there isn't actually any additional threads involved, all of this will run on the normal main thread. Which means that everything simply tries to run serially and the second `f.acquire()` will simply wait (in perpetuity) for something to release that semaphor, but nothing will.

Comment: can you please help me out to get the solution  by modifying the above code I could not grab the concept that you have mentioned

Comment: You need to figure out how to start threads before working with semaphores. I could give you code that does that, but you would have a hole in your knowledge about the basics when you are trying to learn about more advanced techniques. Find [a tutorial about starting threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) and go from there.

Comment: That works for me after creating threads and calling the methods Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class printThread {
    private int n=5;
    private Semaphore f= new Semaphore(1);
    private Semaphore t=new Semaphore(0);

    public void foo(Runnable r)  {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try {
                f.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
           // System.out.print("Foo");
            r.run();
            t.release();
        }
    }

    public void bar(Runnable r1) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            t.acquire();
           // System.out.print("Bar");
            r1.run();
            f.release();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        printThread pt = new printThread();
        Runnable foo=()->System.out.print("Foo");
        Runnable bar=()->System.out.print("Bar");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pt.foo(foo);
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    pt.bar(bar);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The above code works without any issues. I have created two different releases.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the same semaphore in all cases.

Moreover `private Semaphore t=new Semaphore(0);` means that there are NO PERMITS to be given away, meaning that semaphore is always closed.

Comment: I think that is intentional (i.e. each loop acquires one semaphore and releases another for a flip-flop operation). I don't think it's a good idea, but could work in theory (if the loops were actually running in separate threads).

Comment: The same will happen with single semaphore (when fairness=true). There is no need to spread that antipattern.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.